# ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am new to Rails and am working on Michael Hartl's tutorial. I am on chapter 7 and everything was testing fine until I...well truthfully I have no idea. one second its fine, then I added in gravatar_for and now im failing. I have looked around on here for answers and some mentioned putting a ! after downcase which did not work. Here is the error message I am receiving. I know it is right in front of me but after spending two days on this just figured this is the next step. When I run bundle exec rake test I receive this:

```
ERROR["test_should_get_about", StaticPagesControllerTest, 2015-09-09 15:14:50 +0000]
 test_should_get_about#StaticPagesControllerTest (1441811690.06s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
        app/helpers/users_helper.rb:5:in `gravatar_for'
        app/views/static_pages/about.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_static_pages_about_html_erb__2581941383523300906_55646340'
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
    app/helpers/users_helper.rb:5:in `gravatar_for'
    app/views/static_pages/about.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_static_pages_about_html_erb__2581941383523300906_55646340'
    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

20/20: [======] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00
```

this is my app/helpers/user_helper.rb

```
module UsersHelper

# Returns the Gravatar for the given user.
def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 80 })
gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
size = options[:size]
gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
end
end
```

Here is my app/views/static_pages/about.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "About") %>
<h1>About</h1>
<p>
The <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/"><em>Ruby on Rails
Tutorial</em></a> is a
<a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/book">book</a> and
<a href="http://screencasts.railstutorial.org/">screencast series</a>
to teach web development with
<a href="http://rubyonrails.org/">Ruby on Rails</a>.
This is the sample application for the tutorial.
</p>

<%= gravatar_for User.first, size: 50 %>
<%= gravatar_for User.first, size: 200 %>
<%= gravatar_for User.first, size: 80 %>
<%= gravatar_for User.first %>
```

and here is my test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

def setup
@base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
end


test "should get home" do
get :home
assert_response :success
assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"  end

test "should get help" do
get :help
assert_response :success
assert_select "title", "Help | #{@base_title}"
end

test "should get about" do  
get :about
assert_response :success
assert_select "title", "About | #{@base_title}"
end

test "should get contact" do
get :contact
assert_response :success
assert_select "title", "Contact | #{@base_title}"
end
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `user.email` -> user is nil.  Which looking at our code, suggests you have no users as that would mean `User.first` is nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your about.html.erb you have the code:

```
<%= gravatar_for User.first, size: 50 %>
<%= gravatar_for User.first, size: 200 %>
<%= gravatar_for User.first, size: 80 %>
<%= gravatar_for User.first %>
```

which will try to read from the database and find the first User.
This User does not seem to exist and I dont remember that code being there in the rails tutorial (correct me if wrong). The static page test should be independent of any users, and I dont see why you would want the pictures of users on the about site on the first place :)

In short: Remove the mentioned code, and it should run fine.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something stupid i did. I bought the solutions book and this code was added for purposes of illustrations(at least thats what it says). Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no User in your test database, thus `User.first` is `nil` when trying to render

```
<%= gravatar_for User.first, size: 50 %>
```

`nil` is thus passed as `user` to the `gravatar_for` helper which call the `email` method on it :

```
gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
```

This causes the error.

Solutions :

- Make sure `user` exists in the `gravatar_for` helper.
- Populate your test database with at least one user.

Comment: Thanks LapinLove404, I think if i added a user or two that would have fixed the problem!